# Is this possible to use Like with ALL keyword

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have the following,

```
declare @A table (a int)

insert into @A
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3

select a FROM @A 
where a > ALL (select 1 union all select 2)
```

This will work. But I need to use Like instead of greater than here,

```
declare @A table (a int)

insert into @A
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
select 3

select a FROM @A 
where a LIKE ALL (select 1 union all select 2)
```

Please help me.

**Edit**:
Here is the my original old table look like,

```
declare @A table (a varchar(500))

insert into @A
select 'a;b;c' union all
select 'a;d;b' union all
select 'c;a;e'
```

My application is sending values in my SP as 'a;b' or 'b;c;a' etc,

Now I need to Select only those Rows in table @A which have a and b or b and c and a.
I am using split function in my SP to make user input as table.
That's why I need to use Like ALL here. But any other suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: It's not clear what your intentions are. Can you explain in a sentence what the requirements are? What made you lean towards a `LIKE`?

Comment: You need to refine the question -- as is, you've abstracted the issue too much so we can't tell why you want to use `LIKE` or if you actually have to.

Comment: @omg-ponies, I have edited the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use [all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) with like. If I understand you correctly you could use something *like* this instead.

```
declare @T table (ID int primary key, Col varchar(25))

insert into @T
select 1, 'a;b;c' union all
select 2, 'a;b;c' union all
select 3, 'a;d;b' union all
select 4, 'bb;a;e'

declare @Input table(val varchar(10))
insert into @Input values('a')
insert into @Input values('b')

select T.ID
from @T as T
  inner join @Input as I
    on ';'+T.Col+';' like '%;'+I.val+';%'
group by T.ID    
having count(t.ID) = (select count(*) from @Input)
```

Result

```
ID
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want an `IN`?

```
 SELECT a FROM @A WHERE a IN (1,2)
```

Comment: No, I just need instead of checking =,> etc in ALL keyword, I want to use like. I have old table which contains a column with comma separated values and application sending comma separated values to an SP. I am using Split function with. That's why I need Like ALL

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new table which will have search values and then join it by using LIKE statement.

```
create table searchvalues

(

myvalues varchar(30)

)

INSERT INTO SearchValues    
SELECT '%1%'   
UNION SELECT '%2%'


SELECT * FROM @A    
join searchvalues on a like myvalues
```

Comment: This will not work. I have edited the question for better understanding.